# Android DownloadManager failing on HTTP 406 error

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, download-manager, http-error

I am using DownloadManager to download video file from internet to Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES. File is being downloaded, and when the download finishes I get ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcast.

But when I check download status there i get STATUS_FAILED back with REASON 406, which should be HTTP Error 406 Not acceptable. Also DownloadManager automatically deletes that file so I am not able to access it any more.

Strange thing is that it works on most devices and this is happening on Sony D5503 with android 5.1.1.

Do you have any idea why this can happen please?

Comment: FYI, I'm seeing the same 406 consistently for a user with a zte Z777 running 4.3, but can't reproduce in testing.

Comment: Hi. We have figured it out a few days ago. Sony does some check on mime type and if it is not able to verify that file is correct then it deletes the file. And since there are some files which are correct for your app but not for Sony, you are basically screwed :) For us it was fortunately easy to bypass by setting downloadManagerRequest.setMimeType("text/plain");. Though this might not be solution to everyone.